Angular spectrum representation of a Gaussian beam
If we consider the expression for the electric field of a gaussian beam:
$$\vec E(\vec r,z)=\vec E_0 \frac{w_0}{w(z)}e^{-\frac{r^2}{w^2(z)} -i \frac{kr^2}{2R(z)}-i[kz-\arctan(\frac{z}{z_0})]}$$
where:
$\vec r=x\vec e_x + y\vec e_y$
$w_0$ is the beam waist.
$w(z)$ beam radius at distance z from the origin.
$R(z)$ is the radius of the wave front.
If we consider the case (z=0):
$$\vec E(x',y',0)=\vec E_0 e^{-\frac{x'^2+y'^2}{w_0^2}}$$
For the Fourier spectrum we have:
$$\hat E(k_x,k_y,0)=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int \int E_0 E_0 e^{-\frac{x'^2+y'^2}{w_0^2}} e^{-i(k_xk'+k_yy')}dx'dy'=E_0\frac{w_0^2}{4\pi}e^{\frac{-(k_x^2+k_y^2)w_0^2}{4}}$$
The following holds true:
The result shows that the Fourier amplitudes, as a function of the k-vector, are of Gaussian nature. This means that our focus is superimposed by different plane waves, which come under different angles and these angle components have a Gaussian amplitude distribution and interfere in a way that creates a planar wave-front. Moreover, we note that the Gaussian spectrum (last formula above) contains unphysical evanescent components.
I want to ask:

Which are the Fourier amplitudes? What do we consider as Fourier amplitudes here?
What is a Gaussian amplitude distribution? I know a gaussian intensity profile, but amplitude distribution?
How can one tell that the formula above contains evanescent components ?


Can you show a derivation of the right hand side result? I only see a complex term for the $k$.

There was no derivation in the lecture. What I wrote is what was given
